# Dynamically populate the correct DIV with another page content

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple DIVs on my page and I'm having problems populating the correct one with another page view. I'd appreciate some help.

I have a loop that populates a list of DIVs. In the end parsed HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="replycontainer:1">
CONTENT1
<button id="to:1" class="reply">REPLY</button>
</div>  

<div id="replycontainer:2">
CONTENT2
<button id="to:2" class="reply">REPLY</button>
</div> 

<div id="replycontainer:3">
CONTENT3
<button id="to:3" class="reply">REPLY</button>
</div>
```

Now lets say a user clicked on a button "to:3" and now I need to add a "Comment" box to "#replycontainer:3".

My JavaScript, which I thought is correct is not working. It's correctly detecing the clicked DIV class but no other page content is added to the selected DIV.

What could be the issue ?

Javascript/Jquery I use to detect which DIV button was clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button.reply").click(loadComment);
});


function loadComment() {
    var id = this.id.split('to:');
    var postId = id[1];
    var containername = "#replycontainer:" + postId;

    $(containername).load("/Post/Comment");  //MVC Action pointer
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape  ":" with "\\" per jQuery selector API. Bad system for delimiting class names

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

":" is used to define a variety of selectors like ":input", ":checked" etc

Answer (score 1):

Here you reference a div:

```
var containername = "#replycontainer:" + postId;
```

But the container is actually a class:

```
<div class="replycontainer:1>
```

Also, there's a typo. You forgot to close the class token with a double quote.

I've fixed it here:

```
var containername = ".replycontainer:" + postId;
...
<div class="replycontainer:1">
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up when posted the example. Yes, those are IDs , not classes. I use IDs in both DIVs and Javascript below. My Javascript is correct but it's not working. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you miss ' " ' in

```
class="replycontainer:1
```

if it's actual code. And ':' symbol as i know is deprecated in id and class attributes, as i know.

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (“-“), underscores (“_”), colons (“:”), and periods (“.”).

Comment: But if you use [:], if you use this class in CSS file, it will be interpreted as pseudo class (for example :hover, :visited - is familiar?, but :1???)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the value in load() is related to Javascript/Jquery.

```
$(containername).load("/Post/Comment");  //MVC Action pointer
```

The load() could only run some javascript during the page load. But you're trying to run a server script on a client side script. Do take a look of it.

Comment: Seems to work...
I changed : for _ separator and it works. The only thing that I'm confused about that it takes a long time for this logic to be processed. Takes good 5 seconds after the click before something happens on the screen. 
I don't think it has anything to do with what you said but... does it ?